# How to configure Jasmine's (e.g. failSpecWithNoExpectations) in Angular CLI applications?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to use `failSpecWithNoExpectations` from [the Jasmine Configuration docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/Configuration.html) by setting it in `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    failSpecWithNoExpectations: true,
    // etc. all defaults from `ng new`
  });
};
```

But it's not being picked up, not even after a restart of `ng test --watch`. I keep seeing:

> SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should do blahblah

but as a *success*, no failures are reported.

I've tried a few things:

- [searching for generic Jasmine+Angular configuration advice](https://www.google.com/search?q=configure+jasmine+with+angular), no dice
- searching with a [very specific search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+jasmine+"failSpecWithNoExpectations") but none of the results tell me how to do this
- searching my (very plain `ng new`) codebase for "jasmine", but there's no obvious plays to configure things
- I've read through [the Jasmine Configuration doc page](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/Configuration.html) but it merely describes the options
- I've searched [through the Angular testing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing) but all configuration instructions are for CI servers

I'm out of ideas.... What's the idiomatic place to configure Jasmine options in Angular 8+ CLI applications?

Comment: If you look exactly for failSpecWithNoExpectations options, please note that it's a brand new one. You have to have jasmine-core 3.5.0 installed (Angular CLI installs 3.4.0 now). 

And karma-jasmine adapter currently does not process the result of such spec and shows that it passed though jasmine reports 'failed'. They have merged a pull request https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/pull/238 with a fix though it's not released yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jasmine configuration options have to be in client.jasmine section of Karma config. Here is my config derived from Angular CLI default.

```
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false,
      jasmine: {
        failSpecWithNoExpectations: true
      }
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
```

I believe the section is processed by karma-jasmine adapter, and is [described in its docs](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine).